# Derivative for conditional expectation of non-independent gaussian variables is increasing

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics, distributions

Consider two non-independent gaussian random variables:
$$(t,c)∼\text{BiNormal}[(,),(,),]$$

I'm interested in understanding when (i.e. for which values of the distribution parameters) it's true that  $$\frac{\partial E[t |c<f(t)+x]}{\partial x}>0$$
where

```
f[t_]:=b*CDF[NormalDistribution[μa, σa], t]
```

**What I've tried:**

I've tried generating an analytical expression for the conditional
    expectation, but this fails (output same as input)

```
Expectation[t \[Conditioned] c < b*CDF[NormalDistribution[μa, σa], t] + x,
  {t, c} \[Distributed] BinormalDistribution[{μt, μc}, {σt, σc}, ρ]]
```

I've also tried spelling out the expectation via integrals over the
    joint distribution, and then taking derivatives. This does produce a
    valid analytical output, but I cannot reduce the expression (error
    message *"This system cannot be solved with the methods available to
    Reduce"*)

```
D[Integrate[t*PDF[BinormalDistribution[{µt, µc}, {σt, σc}, ρ], {t, c}], 
  {c, -∞, CDF[NormalDistribution[µa, σa], t] + x}, {t, -∞, ∞}]/
  Integrate[PDF[BinormalDistribution[{µt, µc}, {σt, σc}, ρ], {t, c}], 
  {c, -∞, CDF[NormalDistribution[µa, σa], t] + x}, {t, -∞, ∞}], x]
```

---

Here is a related question on the analytical treatment of this problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3692958/parameters-for-which-conditional-expectation-of-non-independent-gaussian-variabl

Comment: Your `Expectation` code has some errors.  There no such `BiNormal` function. It should be `BinormalDistribution`.  There are parentheses where there should be curly brackets.

Comment: Thanks, yes. I've fixed the OP with the actual code. What I had written was not an accurate reflection of the code I had tried running (the output doesnt yield error, it simply returns the input)

Comment: You don't want to use the pipe '|' to mean conditioned. Hit escape and type cond then escape, same for 'dist' (distributed). Still, I don't think _Mathematica_ can calculate it for arbitrary parameters with: `d = BinormalDistribution[{\[Mu]t, \[Mu]c}, {\[Sigma]t, \[Sigma]c}, \
\[Rho]];
f[t_, b_] := b*CDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu]a, \[Sigma]a], t];
D[Expectation[
  t \[Conditioned] c < f[t, b] + x, {t, c} \[Distributed] d], x]`

Comment: @flinty I think the cut-and-paste issue was that the code was inbetween a numbered list.  At least I couldn't get that to show properly.  I edited out the numbered list and hopefully didn't mess up the code.  And I agree, I don't think there's a nice symbolic solution for the particular $f(t)$ chosen.

Comment: @JimB ah, perfect. Yes was struggling with the copy paste. Thanks for fixing it